# Finding the joint distribution of $X_{1:n}$ and $\overline{X}$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I need to show that, given a random sample of independent variables $X_1, ... , X_n$, each following a distribution EXP($\theta$,$\eta$), that is, $f(x_i)=\frac{1}{\theta}\exp(-\frac{x_i-\eta}{\theta})$, the statistics $X_{1:n}$ (the first order statistic) and $\overline{X}=(1/n)(X_1+...+X_n)$ are jointly sufficient for $\theta$ and $\eta$.

I already did this, by using a so-called ''factorization criterion'' (I'm following the terminology of Bein and Engelhardt's ''Introduction to Probability and Mathematical Statistics'') and the indicator function. [See this related post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40587/showing-that-x-1n-is-sufficient-for-eta-by-factorization)

I'd also like to do it using the formula $f_{\vec{X}|\vec{S}}(x_1,...,x_n)=\begin{cases} \frac{f(x_1,...,x_n;\vec{\theta})}{f_{\vec{S}}(\vec{s};\vec{\theta})} & \text{if } \mathit{s}(x_1,...,x_n)=s \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ (one has to show that this is independent of $\vec{\theta}$, the parameters; in this case, $(\theta_1,\theta_2)=(\theta,\eta)$).

(To be honest, I don't understand what that formula really means or where it comes from.)

My trouble is in finding the joint distribution of $X_{1:n}$ and $\overline{X}$. How does one calculate this?

Comment: What do you mean by $X_{1:n}$?

Comment: @Robert: $X_{1:n}=\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

Comment: I changed the title to better reflect what it sounds like you were actually looking for.  If you don't like the new title feel free to change it back.

Comment: This can be done by using the independence of $n(\overline X-X_{1:n})$ and $X_{1:n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your question is really about finding the joint distribution of $X_{1:n}$ and $\overline{X}$, so that's the one I'm going to address.  We'll do this by finding the marginal distribution of $X_{1:n}$ and the conditional distribution of $\overline{X}$ given $X_{1:n}$.  Multiplying them together will give the joint distribution.

**First, the marginal of $X_{1:n}$.**  The distribution of the minimum $X_{1:n}$ of $n$ independent exponential random variables [is again exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables), and it's not too hard to prove that a similar result holds for the exp$(\theta, \eta)$ distribution.  We have that $X_{1:n}$ is exp$(\theta/n,\eta)$; i.e., has pdf
$$f_{X_{1:n}}(x) = \frac{n}{\theta} e^{n(\eta - x)/\theta} {\bf 1}_{(x \geq \eta)}.$$

**Then, the conditional distribution of $\overline{X}$ given $X_{1:n}$.**  Given that $X_{1:n} = a$, each of the other $n-1$ variables from the sample has the cdf $P(X < x| X \geq a)$, where $X$ is exp$(\theta, \eta)$.  As with the [memoryless property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness) of the usual exponential distribution, it is not too hard to show that each of these other variables is exp$(\theta,a)$; i.e., has pdf $$\frac{1}{\theta} e^{(a-x)/\theta} {\bf 1}_{(x \geq a)}.$$

The distribution of $\overline{X}$ given $X_{1:n} = a$, then, is the distribution of $\frac{1}{n}(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{n-1} + a)$, where $X_i$ is exp$(\theta,a)$.  The moment generating function of $\overline{X}$ given $X_{1:n} = a$ can then be found (using standard mgf techniques) to be $$\frac{e^{at}}{(1- \theta t/n)^{n-1}}.$$

Using the [time shift property of the Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) (or by direct calculation) we can see that this is the mgf of what we might reasonably call a gamma$(n-1,\theta/n,a)$ distribution.  (Since the mean of exponentials is gamma, it is reasonable that the mean of shifted exponentials is a shifted gamma.) Thus the pdf of $\overline{X}$ given $X_{1:n} = a$ is $$\left(\frac{n}{\theta}\right)^{n-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n-1)} (\bar{x} - a)^{n-2} e^{n(a - \bar{x})/\theta} {\bf 1}_{(\bar{x} \geq a)}.$$

**Finally, compute the joint distribution.**  Since $f_{X_{1:n},\overline{X}}(a,\bar{x}) = f_{X_{1:n}}(a) f_{\overline{X}|a}(\bar{x}|a)$ we have that

$$f_{X_{1:n},\overline{X}}(a,\bar{x}) = \frac{n}{\theta} e^{n(\eta - a)/\theta}  \left(\frac{n}{\theta}\right)^{n-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n-1)} (\bar{x} - a)^{n-2} e^{n(a - \bar{x})/\theta} {\bf 1}_{(\bar{x} \geq a)} {\bf 1}_{(a \geq \eta)}.$$
Simplifying, the joint pdf of $X_{1:n}$ and $\overline{X}$ that you're looking for is
$$f_{X_{1:n},\overline{X}}(a,\bar{x}) = \left(\frac{n}{\theta}\right)^n \frac{(\bar{x} - a)^{n-2}}{\Gamma(n-1)} e^{n(\eta - \bar{x})/\theta} {\bf 1}_{(\bar{x} \geq a \geq \eta)}.$$